# New battery installation in the Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, battery, macbook-pro-retina

I get a new battery from a repair shop yesterday for the MacBook Pro and the configuration is provided below,

[image]

I read that the battery life for the new installation should be about 7+ hours while I get only about 2+ hours now. The battery configuration is provided below,

[image]

I get the percentage here,

[image]

Is the installation is a new battery or the dealer is deceiving me with an old one? The cycle count is 0, so it might be a new battery. Then why the battery time is so low and also, the time is fluctuating?

Comment: Was the battery cheaper than buying an "official" one? Did you "calibrate" the battery (basically charge fully, turn off & keep charging, drain battery, let sit, charge again)?

Comment: I live in south-east Asia now and don't have access to the Amazon or similar services. Also, it takes 2- weeks time for shipping. 

It was charged all night to the fullest when plugged in. This is the first time I use after replacing the battery. So, it never drained to the bottom. The cycle count is 0 is that mean the battery is new? I didn't know about the calibration but maybe that is the issue.

Comment: The battery is not cheaper I paid $94.30 for the battery, we have high import tax for the electronics

Comment: Sounds like you got a bargain, [Apple says "battery service" for a Macbook Pro Retina is $199, US I'm assuming](https://support.apple.com/mac/repair/service). Anyway I'll post an answer about Macbook battery calibration, that should at lest help some

Comment: @Xen2050 sure, that will be very helpful

Comment: Interestingly, as hour passed after I write the post and took the battery life image. it now shows 33% battery life and have remaining time is 1 hour. Soemthing is wrong here, most likely the calibration mentioned earlier

Comment: The remaining run time is usually an estimate based on average current power usage.  When you first turn it on, it doesn't have much history, and startup isn't typical usage.  The initial time estimate can be way off, even if it's calibrated.

Comment: I calibrated the battery and its providing time about 4-5 hours with moderate CPU usages such as IntelliJ IDE, databases etc

Comment: Ah... I still got below 2 hours. Which is sad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Battery calibration for Macbooks

Lifewire's [Calibrating Your MacBook, Air, or Pro Battery](https://www.lifewire.com/calibrate-macbook-air-battery-2260856) recommends:

> Apple suggests calibrating the battery every few months, but we've found that the appropriate time between calibrations is highly dependent on how, and how often, you use your Mac. With that in mind, it's a safe bet that calibrating your battery as many as four times a year won't be excessive.

The general procedure from [OS X Mavericks: Calibrate the battery in a portable Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14087?locale=en_US) is:

1. Plug in the power adapter and fully charge the battery.
   When the battery is fully charged, the light on the power adapter connector changes to green. If your Mac is on, click the Battery icon in the menu bar to check whether your battery is fully charged.
2. Keep your Mac plugged in for two hours.
   During this time, you can use your Mac or turn it off, as long as the power adapter is plugged in.
3. Disconnect the power adapter. If your Mac isn’t already turned on, turn it on. Then keep your Mac on until the battery runs down and your Mac goes to sleep.
   You can use your Mac during this time. If you don’t use your Mac, make sure it doesn’t go to sleep before the battery runs down.

   [Prevent your Mac from sleeping](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=link&apdid=mchlp1239&viewlocale=en_US&bookId=134327)
4. If you continue to use your Mac and you see the low battery warning, save your work and close all apps. Keep your Mac turned on until it goes to sleep when the battery runs down.
5. After your Mac goes to sleep, turn it off or allow it to sleep for five hours or longer.
6. After five or more hours, connect the power adapter and leave it connected until the battery is fully charged.
   You can use your Mac during this time.

Some more tips from the Lifewire link above:

> ### Tips for Optimizing Battery Usage
>
> There are plenty of ways to reduce battery usage on your Mac; some are obvious, such as dimming the brightness of the display. Bright displays use more energy, so keep it dim as much as possible. You can use the Displays preference pane to adjust display brightness.
>
> Other ways aren't quite as obvious, such as turning off the Wi-Fi capabilities of your Mac when you’re not using a wireless network connection. Even when you're not actively connected to a wireless network, your Mac is expending energy searching for available networks to use. You can turn the Wi-Fi capabilities off either from the Wi-Fi menu bar icon, or the Network preference pane.
>
> Disconnect peripherals, including any attached memory cards. Once again, even when you're not actively using a device, your Mac is checking the various ports for any required service a device may need. Your Mac also supplies power through many of its ports, so disconnecting USB-powered external drives, for example, can extend battery time.

Comment: This is a very helpful post. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome, upvotes &/or green checks are a good way to say "thanks" on SE :) And if the battery doesn't perform good enough after calibrating and a few days of use, then you could try asking the seller about it. Unless the battery looks old & beat up it's hard to tell if it's really new or used, but all that really matters is it works ok